# Unexpected behavior of keras implementation of altered skip-gram model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am tasked to recreate results in the paper: [P2V-MAP: Mapping Market Structures for Large Retail Assortments](https://journals.sagepub.com/eprint/F4SRFRPBNR3VBQHW2QRV/full).

I implemented an altered skip-gram model that takes as input integers corresponding to products in a basket purchased by a customer. Using the skip-gram model it then should create vectors corresponding to latent attributes of the product. It is basically word2vec for products, the thing that is altered is that the similarity score used in word2vec is extended by adding a center specific and context specific bias term learned in the model.

Now onto how I programmed it thus far. First the data: The data is fed into the well known center-context pair style. The model is given a array of `center_products`, `positive_context_products` (products that occur in a basket together) and finally a 2d array of `negative_context_products` ( products that don't occur in a basket together).

Below is the last 10 entries (except for negative context, which has the last 2) of the array in the order: `center`, `positive_context` and `negative_context`.

```
train_center[:10] = [11109 11109 11109 11109 11109 10246 10246 10246 10246 10246]
train_pos_context[:10] = [10246 49683 13176 47209 22035 11109 49683 13176 47209 22035]
train_neg_context[:2] = [[22227 45007  4814 15084 26041  7715 42658 38383 29675 49198 19613 32304
  28985  2295 44418 13166 24852  5068 13176 13170]
 [31506  3339 32478 40469 44990  9392 11512 46106 32478  8277  7461 21903
   7087 32433 13482  9092 23630 28881 42294 42625]]
```

Now onto my problem, I trained the model on the large dataset and a small subset of the dataset. In both training runs the labels fed into the model are as follows:

```
labels[0] = [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

This is the same for each row of labels passed to the model. This data is fed into the following code:

```
from random import random, randint
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, dot, Dense
import numpy as np
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.layers import Reshape


class P2VTensorFlow:
    def __init__(self, seed, num_epoch, train_center, train_pos_context, train_neg_context, num_n_samples, size_vector):
        self.num_epoch = num_epoch
        self.seed = seed
        self.n_products = max(max(x) for x in train_neg_context) + 1
        self.train_center = train_center
        self.train_pos_context = train_pos_context
        self.train_neg_context = train_neg_context
        self.num_n_samples = num_n_samples
        self.size_embedding = size_vector
        self.epoch_done = 0
        self.w_context = None
        self.w_center = None
        self.b_context = None
        self.b_center = None
        self.center_emb = None
        self.positive_emb = None
        self.negative_emb = None
        self.center_bias = None
        self.pos_bias = None
        self.neg_bias = None
        self.model = None

    def initialize_network(self):
        # Inputs needed for model
        center_vector = tf.keras.Input(shape=[1, ], name='center_input')
        positive_vector = tf.keras.Input(shape=[1, ], name='positive_context')
        negative_vector = tf.keras.Input(shape=[self.num_n_samples, ], name='negative_context')

        # Defining embedding layers needed in network
        self.w_context = Embedding(input_dim=self.n_products,
                                   output_dim=self.size_embedding,
                                   input_length=1,
                                   embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(
                                       stddev=.08, seed=self.seed),
                                   name='context_embedding')
        self.w_center = Embedding(input_dim=self.n_products,
                                  output_dim=self.size_embedding,
                                  input_length=1,
                                  embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(
                                      stddev=.08, seed=self.seed),
                                  name='center_embedding')
        self.b_context = Embedding(input_dim=self.n_products,
                                   output_dim=1,
                                   input_length=1,
                                   embeddings_initializer=tf.initializers.Constant(-1.5)
                                   , name='context_bias')
        self.b_center = Embedding(input_dim=self.n_products,
                                  output_dim=1,
                                  input_length=1,
                                  embeddings_initializer=tf.initializers.Constant(-1.5),
                                  name='center_bias')

        self.center_emb = self.w_center(center_vector)
        self.center_emb = Reshape((self.size_embedding,), name='Reshape_center_emb')(self.center_emb)
        self.center_bias = self.b_center(center_vector)
        self.center_bias = Reshape((1,), name='Reshape_center_bias')(self.center_bias)

        self.positive_emb = self.w_context(positive_vector)
        self.positive_emb = Reshape((self.size_embedding,), name='Reshape_positive_emb')(self.positive_emb)
        self.pos_bias = self.b_context(positive_vector)
        self.pos_bias = Reshape((1,), name='Reshape_positive_bias')(self.pos_bias)

        self.negative_emb = self.w_context(negative_vector)
        self.neg_bias = self.b_context(negative_vector)
        self.neg_bias = Reshape((self.num_n_samples,), name='Reshape_negative_bias')(self.neg_bias)

        context_emb = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(self.positive_emb, axis=1), self.negative_emb], 1,
                                name='Context_emb_former')

        # Calculate similarity of center and context vector using dot product
        similarity = tf.einsum('ik,ijk->ij', self.center_emb, context_emb,
                               name='Calculating_similarity_context_center')

        # Calculate score by adding bias to similarity
        score = tf.add(similarity,
                       self.center_bias)
        score = tf.add(score,
                       tf.concat([self.pos_bias, self.neg_bias], axis=1))
        # Create output layer to get probabilities
        output = (Dense(1 + self.num_n_samples, activation='sigmoid', name='Calculate_probabilities')(score))

        # Create model
        self.model = Model([center_vector, positive_vector, negative_vector],
                           output,
                           name='product2vec')

        self.model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                           optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                           metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])

    def train_network(self):
        tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=r".\logs", histogram_freq=1,
                                                              write_graph=True, write_images=True, embeddings_freq=1)
        labels = np.zeros((self.train_center.shape[0], self.num_n_samples + 1))
        for i in range(self.train_center.shape[0]):
            index = randint(0, self.num_n_samples)
            labels[i][0] = 1

        test_model = Model(inputs=self.model.input, outputs=self.model.get_layer(
            'Calculate_probabilities').output)
        output_test = test_model.predict(
            [self.train_center[:10], self.train_pos_context[:10], self.train_neg_context[:10]])
        print(output_test)
        print(self.train_center[:10])
        print(self.train_pos_context[:10])
        print(self.train_neg_context[:10])
        print(labels[:10])

        self.model.fit(x=[self.train_center, self.train_pos_context, self.train_neg_context],
                       y=[labels],
                       epochs=self.num_epoch,
                       shuffle=True,
                       batch_size=64,
                       validation_split=0.2,
                       callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

        test_model = Model(inputs=self.model.input, outputs=self.model.get_layer(
            'Calculate_probabilities').output)
        output_test = test_model.predict(
            [self.train_center[:10], self.train_pos_context[:10], self.train_neg_context[:10]])
        print(output_test)

        self.model.save("model.h5")

        for i in range(self.num_epoch):
            pass


# Load small dataset from disk
center = np.loadtxt('small_center_products', delimiter=",", dtype=np.int32)
pos_context = np.loadtxt('small_positive_context_products', delimiter=",", dtype=np.int32)
neg_context = np.loadtxt('small_negative_context_products', delimiter=",", dtype=np.int32)

test = P2VTensorFlow(1000, 2, center, pos_context, neg_context, 20, 30)
test.initialize_network()
test.train_network()
```

However when training and tracking accuracy I get some weird results. Firstly, the accuracy starts at 0.0000e+00 and very slowly goes up to 0.0415. The output from training the model on my full dataset for 2 epochs is [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61eyN.png) The accuracy only seems to go up because the output of the Dense sigmoid activation layer is as follows:

```
output =  [1.0000000e+00 2.8150848e-11 2.8790569e-11 2.5585041e-11 2.7863401e-11
  2.3193829e-11 3.2485150e-11 2.8669577e-11 2.5894085e-11 3.0460568e-11
  2.9323939e-11 2.8722720e-11 2.6484696e-11 2.7809879e-11 2.9465336e-11
  2.6407571e-11 2.9402460e-11 3.4942400e-11 2.7540987e-11 3.1028721e-11
  2.4985264e-11]
```

I am stumped, the model firstly does not seem to track accuracy properly. I looked on this site for similar problems, but the only people that also had the weird accuracy used linear activation.
Secondly, the model seems to perfectly predict if products are in a basket together or not. Which seems like it's very unlikely it's not a bug or mistake on my part.

Finally if you have any comments on lay-out, code quality or weird code please say so, I always want to learn to make better code.